# Make a "li" invisible in masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have the following code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li  id ="NewTicketsli" class="encours"><a href="/Creation_Incidents/Creation_Incidents.aspx">Nouveau Ticket</a></li>
        <li class="encours"><a href="/TicketsEnCours/TicketsEnCours.aspx">Tickets en Cours</a></li>
        <li class="encours"><a href="/Incident_EnCours/Incidents_EnCours.aspx">Tickets en Cours</a></li>
        <%-- <li class="encours"><a href="/Incident_EnCours/Incidents_EnCours.aspx">Incidents En
            Cours</a></li>--%>
        <li class="clotures"><a href="/Incidents_Clotures/Incidents_Clotures.aspx">Incidents
            Clôturés</a></li>
        <li class="stat"><a href="/Statistiques/Statistiques.aspx">Suivi crédit temps</a></li>
        <li class="stat"><a href="/Incidents_Clotures/TicketsRefuses.aspx">Tickets refusés</a></li>
        <li class="stat"><a href="/TicketsEnCours/test.aspx">TEST</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In an event i need to set **the first li invisible or not.**
I tried to give it an ID. But i can't manage to get access to anything.

Thanks in advance to your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add also `runat="server"` to access the control on the server side

```
<li  id ="NewTicketsli" runat="server" class="encours">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Runat=server

```
<li  id ="NewTicketsli" **runat=server** class="encours"><a href="/Creation_Incidents/Creation_Incidents.aspx">Nouveau Ticket</a></li>
```

Then you can access the object

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewTicketsli.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery, its easy.

```
$("#NewTicketsli").addclass("yourClassName");
```

while

```
.yourClassName{
//your css properties
}
```

Comment: It should be `$("#NewTicketsli")...` (Remember the hash)